# Faster way to create cost matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) in scipy which takes as an input the cost matrix of two sets of points. This just means each element in array `x` is passed into function `f` with each element in array `y`. I currently implemented this with a nested for loop in python. Here is a basic example of what I do:

```
def f(a, b):

    return a * b

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

cost_mat = np.zeros((x.shape[0], y.shape[0]))

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y.shape[0]):
        cost_mat[i, j] = f(x[i], y[j])

print(cost_mat)

>> out:
[[1., 2., 3.]
 [2., 4., 6.]
 [3., 6., 9.]]
```

Is there a faster way to do this? For example, vectorizing it somehow?

Comment: Yes that should be right. Each `x` need to be matched with each `y`. So first outer-loop:`a=x[0], b=y[0]`, `a=x[0], b=y[1]` `a=x[0], b=y[2]` then for second outer-loop: `a=x[1], b=y[0]`, `a=x[1], b=y[1]`, `a=x[1], b=y[2]` etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this work :

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)
y = np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)

cost_mat = x * y.T
```

cost_matrix is

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Let's time both solutions with bigger arrays :

```
x = np.random.rand(10000,1)
y = np.random.rand(10000,1)

def f(a, b):
    return a * b

# Start timing here
cost_mat1 = np.zeros((x.shape[0], y.shape[0]))

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y.shape[0]):
        cost_mat1[i, j] = f(x[i], y[j])

# Wall time: 2min 13s
```

Using transpose is way faster :

```
# Start timing here
cost_mat2 = x * y.T
# Wall time: 395 ms
```

And then check that

```
np.array_equal(cost_mat1, cost_mat2)
```

Returns true

Comment: Thanks! I need it to be passed an arbitrary cost function `f` so I used the `np.tile()` function you previously suggested: `x_ = np.tile(x, (x.shape[0],1)).reshape(x.shape[0], y.shape[0], x.shape[1])`, `y_ = np.tile(y, (1, y.shape[0])).reshape(x.shape[0], y.shape[0], y.shape[1])` and then `cost_mat = f(x_, y_).T`. This allows it to work when `x` and `y` are also not the same shape (i.e. different number of points) like it would with the nested for loop.